# Get last n elements in a list in DrRacket, without list-ref

Tags: scheme, racket

I know how to get the first `n` elements in a list,

```
(define (countup n ls)
  (cond
    [(zero? n) '()]
    [else (cons (first ls) (countup (sub1 n) (rest ls)))]))
```

but how can I do something like this for the *last* `n` elements in a list *(without using list-ref)*?

If I call `(countup 3 '(a b c d e))`, I get `(list a b c)`. I need to be able to enter `(counter 3 '(a b c d e))` and get `(list c d e)`.

I need error messages in case the number `n` given is bigger than the list's length.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the built-in `take-right` procedure, it does exactly what you need:

```
(take-right '(a b c d e) 3)
=> '(c d e)
```

Or you can implement it from scratch, using primitive procedures:

```
(define (counter n lst)
  (define (move n lst)
    (if (zero? n)
        lst
        (move (sub1 n) (rest lst))))
  (define (trim-left lst rst)
    (if (empty? rst)
        lst
        (trim-left (rest lst) (rest rst))))
  (trim-left lst (move n lst)))
```

It also works as expected:

```
(counter 3 '(a b c d e))
=> '(c d e)
```

Comment: I need to be able to do it without using take-right

Comment: altho I do thank you for trying to help, I can't use trim, take, move, or list-ref.

Comment: I'm _not_ using any of those, I simply defined two helper procedures that happen to be called `move` and `trim-left`. It's ok to use additional helpers, you can't solve this problem easily without them anyway.

Comment: OK I got locals, but I need to add errors if the number is bigger than the size of the list

Comment: @KrissyMichaelsson after you study this code, you should be able to insert the error messages. Look into `move`. How will the error condition manifest itself there? Is the code as currently written handling this situation?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I would use a local fn to chop of items from the left and then return the remaining items. The following also returns '() if asked to return a Negative number of items. You may want to treat this as an error as well. #f signals an error in your input ie trying to take more items than the list contains

```
(define (counter n loN)
  (define (acc loN c)
    (cond [(null? loN) '()]
          [(> c 0) (acc (cdr loN) (sub1 c))]
          [else loN]))
  ;in
  (let ((c (- (length loN) n)))
    (cond ; [(>= 0 n) #f]
          [(positive? c) (acc loN c)] 
          [else #f])))

(check-equal? (counter 3 '(a b c d e)) '(c d e))
(check-equal? (counter 6 '(a b c d e)) #f)
(check-equal? (counter -3 '(a b c d e)) '())
(check-equal? (counter 0 '(a b c d e)) '())
```